# send email to multiple email address

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
follower = FollowerEmail.objects.filter(user=report_id)
list=[]        
for email in follower:
    list.append(email.email)
       ''''''
       ''''''
if 'email' in request.POST:
    subject, from_email, to = 'New Report Created',user.email, person.parent_email
    html_content = render_to_string('report/mail.html',{'person':person,
                                                             'report':report,
                                                             'list':list,
                                                             })
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to],bcc=['list'], cc=['person.email'])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

models.py

```
class FollowerEmail(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    email = models.CharField('Email', max_length=100)
```

I tried it in the above manner,no emails are send,getting 500s in console.

If i pass a email address directly to the bcc field,mail is sending but i want to send email to the email id saved in FollowerEmail table.Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide any traceback of the exception?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. `if` block is indented one level to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for email in follower:
    list.append(email)
```

This isn't a list of emails this is a list of people. try

```
list.append(email.email)
```